# How to get post id with Beautiful Soup web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a template for extracting news from websites for semantic analysis. I've just started learning to do web scraping with bs4 and selenium.

I could achieve to separate and get the title, subtitle and date from each news as following (already tested and working for any news):

```
title = soup.find_all('h1')[1].text
subtitle = soup.find_all('h2')[0].text
date = soup.find_all("span")[39].text
```

Now I'm trying to get the id from the post so I could save each news as a .txt file and the filename would be the id from the post.

If I use `soup.find("article")` I get the following:

```
<article class="article post" id="post-518551">
<div class="post-header">
<div class="category">
<a href="/entretenimento">Entretenimento</a> </div>
<h1 class="title">No Dia dos Namorados, Manu Gavassi assume relacionamento: “Eu te amo”</h1>
<h2 class="description">A cantora utilizou as redes sociais para publicar um clique fofo ao lado de Jullio</h2>
<span class="author">

(...)
```

**I need only to extract the post id from the first line. I've tried several commands within `soup.find` but I couldn't debug how to get it. Everything I try returns to me the full `article` code.**

Someone can help me?

Many thanks for the community!

Comment: hi there good day dear guilherme - many thanks for this helpful question. It is a great asset for learing - i am glad. Btw. wiith a url we even could learn more..

Comment: An example url from this project: https://capricho.abril.com.br/comportamento/11-expectativas-sobre-o-inverno-que-nao-se-tornam-realidade-no-brasil/

Comment: many many thanks for this greatr help - your awesome. I am very glad

Answer (score 2):

If `html_doc` is your HTML snippet from the question, then:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

article = soup.find("article")
post_id = article["id"].split("-")[1]
print(post_id)
```

Prints:

```
518551
```

---

If you want full ID (with `post-`):

```py
post_id = article["id"]
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you a lot. It worked perfectly. Sorry if it looks like a dumb question. I've just started to learn web scraping.